# How do I elegantly remove ellipses of n-length from strings (NLP with spacy)?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I am currently performing data cleaning on this [spam text message dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/team-ai/spam-text-message-classification). There are many ellipses in these text message, for example:

```
mystr = 'Go until jurong point, crazy.. Available only in bugis n great world la e buffet... Cine there got amore wat...'
```

As you can see, there are ellipses with 2 periods (`..`) or 3 periods (`...`)

My initial solution was to write a function `spacy_tokenizer` that tokenizes my strings, removes stopwords as well as punctuations:

```py
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

stopWords = set(stopwords.words('english'))
print(stopWords)

import string
punctuations = string.punctuation
```

```py
def spacy_tokenizer(sentence):
    # Create token object
    mytokens = nlp(sentence)
    # Case normalization and Lemmatization
    mytokens = [ word.lemma_.lower() if word.lemma_ != "-PRON-" else word.lower_ for word in mytokens ]
    # Remove stop words and punctuations
    mytokens = [ word.strip(".") for word in mytokens if word not in stopWords and word not in punctuations ]
    # return preprocessed list of tokens
    return mytokens
```

However, this function doesn't get rid of the ellipses

```
IN: print(spacy_tokenizer(mystr))
OUT: ['go', 'jurong', 'point', 'crazy', '', 'available', 'bugis', 'n', 'great', 'world', 'la', 'e', 'buffet', '', 'cine', 'get', 'amore', 'wat', '']
```

As you can see, there are tokens with `len(token) = 0` that appear as `''`

My workaround is to add another list comprehension to `spacy_tokenizer` that looks something like this: `[ word for word in mytokens if len(word) > 0]`

```
def spacy_tokenizer(sentence):
    # Create token object
    mytokens = nlp(sentence)
    # Case normalization and Lemmatization
    mytokens = [ word.lemma_.lower() if word.lemma_ != "-PRON-" else word.lower_ for word in mytokens ]
    # Remove stop words and punctuations
    mytokens = [ word.strip(".") for word in mytokens if word not in stopWords and word not in punctuations ]
    # remove empty strings
    mytokens = [ word for word in mytokens if len(word) > 0]
    return mytokens

IN: print(spacy_tokenizer(mystr))
OUT: ['go', 'jurong', 'point', 'crazy', 'available', 'bugis', 'n', 'great', 'world', 'la', 'e', 'buffet', 'cine', 'get', 'amore', 'wat']
```

So the new function gives the expect result, bu it's not the most elegant solution I think. Does anyone have any alternative ideas?

Comment: Inside your `spacy_tokenizer` function, you can process the strings first to remove punctuations using `sentence = ''.join(i for i in sentence if i not in punctuations)` then tokenize and continue

Comment: @Shijith thanks but unfortunately this means that contractions like `I'll` will be changed to `ill` and won't be recognized as stop words.

Comment: @Shijith although this did give me an idea! I simply separated stop word and punctuation removal. `mytokens = [ word.strip(".") for word in mytokens if word not in stopWords ]` then `mytokens = [ word for word in mytokens if word not in punctuations]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will remove ellipses of 2 or 3 periods:

```
import re

regex = r"[.]{2,3}"
test_str = "Go until jurong point, crazy.. Available only. in bugis n great world la e buffet... Cine there got amore wat..."
subst = ""

result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str)

if result:
    print (result)
```

You can also play around with it [here](https://regex101.com/r/jYJY82/1/) if you want.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't care about punctuation at all (it seems that way, since you also remove the comma in your example sentence), you should consider just removing all punctuation.

```
import re

sent = 'Go until jurong point, crazy.. Available only in bugis n great world la e buffet... Cine there got amore wat...'
multipunc = re.compile("[\.,]+")
sent = multipunc.sub(" ", sent).lower().split()
```

This function currently does not take into account punctuation other than `.` and `,`. If you want to remove anything but alphanumeric characters, you could consider using the `\w` character class.